# Does an external javascript file reload between HTML pages?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a basic HTML/CSS/JavaScript quiz website.

I am using an external JavaScript for data collection from an HTML form in JavaScript as such:

```
var userInfo = [];
function savePerson(form)
{
    userInfo[0] = form.store.value;
    userInfo[1] = form.employeeId.value;
    userInfo[2] = form.fName.value;
    userInfo[3] = form.lName.value;
};
```

This works just fine.

Now, I need to go to a different HTML page but keep this the values in array. Does JavaScript reload between HTML files? If so How can I keep the values from a script through multiple pages?

Comment: You can only do this if you keep the values in a cookie (or `LocalStorage`), or post them around in form data / querystring. The latter being a highly bad way of doing this for a quiz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must either store them at the client-side, or at the server-side.

For server-side-storage, you have to send the data to the server via ajax and there save it in any kind of database.

On the client-side you can store the data either in cookies, localstorage, indexeddb, or websql.

A simple solution would be:

```
localStorage.setItem('myPerson', JSON.stringify(userInfo));
```

Comment: I believe this will be the simplest solution, the data isn't super confidential so server side might be a bit overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the array as a .js file using the file save facilities of html5. And then in the other html page you would load the js file as an external script.

Answer (score 0):

If using sensitive information you'd probably want to use a back-end service to store and retrieve such data, but local storage or cookies can be used in most cases.

**Heres an example using Local Storage**

Set the item:

```
localStorage.setItem('userInfo', userInfo);
```

then on your next page use this to get the item:

```
var userInfo = localStorage.getItem("userInfo");
```

Answer (score 0):

use localstorage

```
//save datas:
localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(info));


//get datas:
var data=localStorage.getItem('data');
```